# How to record adding to shopping card operation with Blazemeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

I want to run a test scenario where user add item to the shopping cart. I am recording the script using Blazemeter but when I record I only see going to the product page and going to the shopping card page. But I also want to record when it is adding item in the shopping cart. Can I get some suggestion on this please. Thanks!

Comment: If it is possible, could you please share the website link so that we can look for if there's something really missing on the website, or is it just you missing something? :)

Answer (score 0):

BlazeMeter Chrome Extension is only recording [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)/[HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) network requests, if "adding to shopping card" operation is happening only in your browser and doesn't generate a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - the BlazeMeter Chrome Extension won't "catch" it (and none of other recording solutions will do)

So if you're focusing on the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end) side of things - you need to look at the next business action, i.e. "checkout" or something like this, most probably this request will involve the item(s) from the shopping card.

If you're interested in how much time it took to add the product to the shopping card and it happens only in the browser - you will have to do it in the real browser, there is [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) plugin which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework